# corner radius for cells view

Tags: ios, swift

I am using tablet view and  my table view is grouped.I use single prototype cell. In my cell, I use `UIView` and want to make corner only first cell  view top and last cell view bottom. I use this code below. when table view first loading its only show first cell view left corner but not for right and bottom cell view.when I scrolling last and come back first it's working correctly. Need help pls. Thank you
and Sorry for my bad English

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // tableview section
        let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyTableViewCell
        if indexPath.row == 0{

            cell.myview.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 10)

        } else if indexPath.row ==  3 {
            cell.myview.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 10)

        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       // let cell = cell as! MyTableViewCell
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Comment: Check in the debugger if `self.bounds` returns the correct value (in `roundCorners`). The first time the cell is created, the layouting might not have run yet and `self.bounds` might be invalid.

Comment: Try to add cell.myview.layer.maskTobounds = true

Comment: Thanks @Codo. I get my error and Now i am changing my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should also handle rows in the middle like this:

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0: //round top
    cell.myview.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 10)
case 3: //round bottom
    cell.myview.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 10)
default: //remove rounded corners. This is important since cells are reused
    cell.myview.roundCorners(corners: [.allCorners], radius: 0)
}
```

Comment: My code works but not for the first time when tableview first load.when my cell invisible after scrolling and again come back to first cell its show me the correct way. I am looking for the first time why it's not working